# Problem in series expansion

Tags: analysis

I have some problem in understanding this text from The Princeton Companion to Mathematics:

> Suppose that one seeks an expansion of $f(x) = \sqrt{x + i}$ in powers of $i$. In general, only integer powers will be involved. Terms of the form $i^{m/n}$ do not make sense, says Lagrange, since the expression of the function $\sqrt{x+i}$ is only two-valued, while $i^{m/n}$
>   has n values. Hence the series $\sqrt{x + i} =\sqrt{x} + pi + qi^2 + \ldots + ti^k + \ldots$ obtains its two values from the term $\sqrt{x}$, and all other powers must be integral.

What does the author mean when he says that the expression of $\sqrt{x+i}$ is only two-valued and secondly, how does $i^{m/n}$ has n values? Also, how does the series expansion obtain its two values from $\sqrt x$, which has a single value ?

Comment: I couldn't find a good title and didn't know which tag was appropriate for the question. Please feel free to make useful edits.

Comment: The square root function outputs two values, since there are two square roots of any number. So $\sqrt{x+i}$ outputs two square roots of ${x+i}$. In general for the n-th root of something, there are n values. So $i^{m/n}$ is the n-th root of $i^{m}$ and hence has n values.

Comment: @ChickenP: Did Lagrange mean to include the complex roots of a number? I thought that he was talking only about real roots.